# In R how to make all the values of date time in a column unique

Tags: r, data.table, xts, zoo

Subset of my data looks like:

```
df <- structure(list(idx = 1:5, start_time = structure(c(1325574000, 
                                                             1325575800, 1325575800, 1325575800, 1325577600), class = c("POSIXct", 
                                                                                                                        "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), sorted = "AppointmentStartTime", class = c("data.table", 
                                                                                                                                                                                               "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .internal.selfref = '<pointer: 0x00000000025c1ef0>')

   idx          start_time
1:   1 2012-01-03 07:00:00
2:   2 2012-01-03 07:30:00
3:   3 2012-01-03 07:30:00
4:   4 2012-01-03 07:30:00
5:   5 2012-01-03 08:00:00
```

I'm able to make time unique using:

```
xts(1:5, order.by = make.time.unique((as.POSIXct(df$start_time))))



                    [,1]
2012-01-03 07:00:00    1
2012-01-03 07:30:00    2
2012-01-03 07:30:00    3
2012-01-03 07:30:00    4
2012-01-03 08:00:00    5
```

But, I want to create a new column in `df` with unique values. I tried something in `data.table` like:

```
df[, unique_time := xts(1:5, order.by = make.time.unique((as.POSIXct(df$start_time))))]
```

It gives me an output:

```
idx          start_time      unique_time
1:   1 2012-01-03 07:00:00           1
2:   2 2012-01-03 07:30:00           2
3:   3 2012-01-03 07:30:00           3
4:   4 2012-01-03 07:30:00           4
5:   5 2012-01-03 08:00:00           5
```

I want my desired output to be something like:

```
idx          start_time              unique_time
1       2012-01-03 07:00:00   2012-01-03 07:00:00    1
2       2012-01-03 07:30:00   2012-01-03 07:30:00    2
3       2012-01-03 07:30:00   2012-01-03 07:30:00    3
4       2012-01-03 07:30:00   2012-01-03 07:30:00    4
5       2012-01-03 08:00:00   2012-01-03 08:00:00    5
```

Comment: do you need `cbind(df,xts(1:5, order.by = make.time.unique((as.POSIXct(df$start_time))))`??

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't work.

Comment: That seems the values obtained from xts are factor: you can try:`cbind(df,as.character(xts(1:5, order.by = make.time.unique((as.POSIXct(df$start_time)))))`

Comment: It gives values like 1,2,3,4,5 in resulting column.

Comment: even after using `as.character`?

Comment: Yes, even after using `as.character`.

Comment: They're actually `xts` objects (examine with `str(df$unique_time)`), just as they were in your first example, when you generated the object as a vector, rather than a column in a data table.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting exactly what you want. Look at `df$unique_time`

```
df
   idx          start_time unique_time
1:   1 2012-01-03 07:00:00           1
2:   2 2012-01-03 07:30:00           2
3:   3 2012-01-03 07:30:00           3
4:   4 2012-01-03 07:30:00           4
5:   5 2012-01-03 08:00:00           5

df$unique_time
# 2012-01-03 07:00:00 2012-01-03 07:30:00 2012-01-03 07:30:00 
#              1                   2                   3 
# 2012-01-03 07:30:00 2012-01-03 08:00:00 
#              4                   5
```

Comment: Oh yes. But, then while viewing `df` in viewer of RStudio or by printing `df` why it's not showing complete values in  `unique_time` column.

Comment: That's a design decision by `data.table`.

Comment: That's weird, I have never come across such problem before.

Comment: I don't know if it's a problem... it depends on what you want to do with your data. If you want to do something that you can't with this column, the issue isn't that you put it into a column of a data table, but that you converted it to an `xts` object

Comment: I didn't try next steps which I would want to take. What I'm looking for is ways to make date time column values unique in time series data. I'm sure there must be several ways of doing it and people must be using it.

Comment: I'm not restricted to `xts` approach. It was just used as an example of what I tried.

Comment: You've done that. You have an extensible time series object with unique values.

Comment: I'm not sure about this because when I'm subsetting my real data it just print a number like 211233. But, when I use `$` for say top 5 records, it get's printed with time. I want to do a rolling join on this column after this. So, want to be 100% sure about this approach. Also, would like to see if there are other ways to do it.

Comment: What behavior are you looking for that you don't currently have?

Comment: I want to count number of records for an idx in a time period of say 1 year. For that I want to make date and time column unique.